# Difference between the implementation of var in Javascript and C#

Tags: c#, javascript, .net, linq, var

I would like to ask a theoretical question. If I have, for example, the following C# code in Page_load:

```
cars = new carsModel.carsEntities();

var mftQuery = from mft in cars.Manufacturers 
               where mft.StockHeaders.Any(sh=> sh.StockCount>0) 
               orderby mft.CompanyName 
               select new {mft.CompanyID, mft.CompanyName};
               // ...
```

Questions:

1. This code uses the `var` keyword. What is the benefit of this construct?
2. What is the key difference between the implementation of `var` in Javascript and C#?

Comment: You might as well ask about the difference between "die" in English and "die" in German. One is the verb to death and and the singular of dice, the other is an article and pronoun (in both cases, I just picked two common meanings, there are of course more). They're completely different things (they even have different pronouncations) that happen to look the same when written down. Similar for `var` in C# and JS.

Answer (score 79, accepted):

JavaScript is a dynamically typed language, while c# is (usually) a statically typed language.  As a result, comparisons like this will always be problematic.  But:

JavaScript's `var` keyword is somewhat similar to C#'s `dynamic` keyword.  Both create a variable whose type will not be known until runtime, and whose misuse will not be discovered until runtime.  This is the way JavaScript **always** is, but this behavior is brand new to C# 4.

```
dynamic foo = new DateTime();
foo.bar();  //compiles fine but blows up at runtime.
```

JavaScript has nothing to match C#'s `var`, since JavaScript is a dynamically typed language, and C#'s `var`, despite popular misconception, creates a variable whose type is **known at compile time**.  C#'s `var` serves two purposes: to declare variables whose type is a pain to write out, and to create variables that are of an anonymous type, and therefore *have* no type that can be written out by the developer.

For an example of the first:

```
var conn = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection("....");
```

Anonymous type projections from Linq-to-Sql or Entity Framework are a good example of the second:

```
var results = context.People.Where(p => p.Name == "Adam")
                            .Select(p => new { p.Name, p.Address });
```

Here `results` is of type `IQueryable<SomeTypeTheCompilerCreatedOnTheFly>`.  No matter how much you might like to write out the actual type of results, instead of just writing `var`, there's no way to since you have no knowledge of the type that the compiler is creating under the covers for your anonymous type—hence the terminology: this type is **anonymous**

In both cases the type is known at **compile time**, and in both cases, subsequently saying either

```
conn = new DateTime();
```

or

```
results = new DateTime();
```

would result in a **compiler error**, since you're setting `conn` and `results` to a type that's not compatible with what they were **declared as**.

Comment: Great answer!  It would be more accurate if Microsoft used the word infer instead of var, but for the sake of brevity, I think they picked the right one. After all these years, it still amazes me how elegant .NET is compared to other development technologies. I guess it's from Microsoft development teams having to eat their own dog food.  BTW, if you use Resharper, the workings of var becomes immediately apparent.

Comment: @Joel, thank you, and yes, I find C# incredibly elegant.  Eric Lippert and company did a great job.

Comment: @Joel: The only issue with C# is that it's C-based, and so brings with it many of the poor syntax-choices from C.  Of course, if it wasn't C-based it wouldn't have nearly the adoption-rate, so that *was* the right choice... it was a problem with programming-society, not a mistake from the C#-designers :\

Comment: Also, the var keyword in JavaScript does nothing with the variable type, but it does affect the variable scope. A variable declared without var becomes a global variable. One declared with the var keyword is local (in JavaScript, that is function scope, not block scope).

Comment: @Johan - very true. C# has no equivalent for implicit globals.

Answer (score 10):

a) C#'s `var` lets you avoid writing an explicit type upon variable declaration. This makes your code more compact, also sometimes the type of the expression on the right side of the declaration is complicated and in the same time you are not interested what the actual type is.

b) Javascript's `var` is like C#'s `dynamic`. It lets you declare a variable but you can change its type.

```
var i = 1; 
i = "foo";  // legal in Javascript, illegal in C#
```

Answer (score 7):

The only thing they have in common is that they are used to declare local variables.

The C# equivalent of JS `var` is [`dynamic`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264736.aspx). But since most C# users prefer static typing it is usually only used in interop scenarios of some kind(with COM or a dynamically typed language).

[C# `var`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383973.aspx) still uses static typing, but with an inferred type. Since JS only supports dynamic typing, there is no equivalent.

In this context explicit static typing isn't possible, since `new {mft.CompanyID, mft.CompanyName}` creates an [anonymous type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397696.aspx), so implicit static typing with `var` is used.

Answer (score 1):

var in C# is dynamic at design time but staticly typed at compile time. You will see that if you do:

```
var mftQuery = from mft in cars.Manufacturers
    where mft.StockHeaders.Any(sh=> sh.StockCount>0) 
    orderby mft.CompanyName
    select new {mft.CompanyID, mft.CompanyName};
```

and then:

```
mftQuery = "Hello world!";
```

It will not compile and complain about missmatching types even though you didn't specify any type.

This is a useful productivity enhancement because you can easily change return types to similar types without breaking anything and it is easier to write. A stupid example:

```
foreach(var animal in GetCats()){
   Console.WriteLine(animal.Owner);
}
```

could be changed to:

```
foreach(var animal in GetDogs()){
   Console.WriteLine(animal.Owner);
}
```

Comment: What do you mean "design time"?

Answer (score 0):

And to answer your question **1**, the benefit of using `var` keyword in the presented code is at may be difficult to come up with the resulting type for the LINQ query and can be easily affected by the change to the query. In fact, its introduction to C# coincide with the premiere of LINQ.

Reassuming, it is to make the life of programmer easier and also to remove the redundancy of `Type t = new Type()`.